# Gtk skip_taskbar_hint (seen in Glade-ui-Designer) äquivalent in Qt

Tags: qt, gtk, pyqt, taskbar, ewmh

With Glade Designer that lets you set up Gtk-Ui's you can check the option that windows are not shown in the taskbar (unter linux, e.g. in Ubuntu this is the launcher on the left hand side). If I take a look at the ui-file generated by Glade, it says `<property name="skip_taskbar_hint">True</property>` However I believe that this option is not Gtk-specific, and want to apply this one on my PyQt4-app.

Right now I can only disable the window in the taskbar if i set the hint with the programm devilspie (that communicates with EWMH-standard) to skip_tasklist, which is too much for me.

Does anybody know such an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `Qt::SplashScreen` does the same effect. You can add this flag to your widget using the following code:

```
setWindowFlags(windowFlags() & Qt::SplashScreen);
```

[Source](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/55685-Tell-the-window-manager-to-skip-the-taskbar-%28launcher%29)